# Can't Print a list value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to organize my server logs a little that is split by "|"
and now I want to change the position of the items when I put them in a list and trying to print it out to save it in a new file it gives me

```
print(result[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It is the same with every position in the list not only 0

```
with open("logs-DD-MM-YYYY.txt") as f:
     for line in f:
         result = line.split('|')
         print(result[0])
```

Comment: @roganjosh blank line cannot result in an empty list `"".split("|")` ==> `['']`

Comment: What is `line`?  What is `result`?

Comment: since they are pulling the first item it would ALWAYS return a result even if it was blank despite the split

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte yeah, I just realised with `a = ''.split('|')[0]`. In that case, I don't know what's happening tbh

Comment: @roganjosh I tried his code and it should work for any input... I think the error is somewhere else and he hasn't shared enough information for us to find out.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] because it's hard to see how this might happen

Comment: If you upload the log to Pastebin I can take a crack at it

Comment: i didnt write anything more than i posted ther is no variables

Answer (score 1):

Before printing the result[0], i would check if the result list is non-empty. i think you might be encountering an empty line. thats why you are seeing an index out of range error. Use try catch to catch the exception in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in a `try: & except:` clause.

```
with open("logs-DD-MM-YYYY.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            result = line.split('|')
            print(result[0])
        except:
            print("ERROR IN FORMATTING: {}".format(line))
```

This will allow python to print where you are experiencing the error at least. Then you can solve the problem from there!